# .join() y .replace() en python

Tags: python

Tengo este trozo de programa y me pregunto como sería sin usar **.join()** y **.replace()**, supongo que hay que utilizar **for**, pero no me han enseñado aun. Gracias!.

```
def listarEstados():

    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        strA = "\n".join(states)
        strB = strA.replace(",",": ")
    print(strB)
```

Comment: No debería ser: strA = "\n".join(lector) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no he interpretado mal, lo que realmente buscas es reemplazar el separador `(,)` por `": "`. En ese caso, si vas a hacer uso de `csv.reader`, el cual retorna un objeto que implementa el protocolo iterador, el código debería ser:

```
import csv

def listar_estados():    
    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        str_a = "\n".join(": ".join(row) for row in lector))
        print(str_a)
```

Sin usar `str.join` ni formateo de cadenas, puedes concatenar cadenas, pero no hagas jamás ésto en la "vida real", es muy muy muy ineficiente, cada concatenación crea un nuevo objeto `str` en memoria, dado que son inmutables:

```
import csv

def listar_estados():    
    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        str_a = ""
        for row in lector:
            for i in range(len(row) - 1):
                str_a += row[i] + ": "
            str_a += row[-1] + "\n"
        print(str_a)
```

Si sabes de antemano las columnas del csv puedes simplificar, por ejemplo, para dos columnas:

```
import csv

def listar_estados():
    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        str_a = ""
        for col_a, col_b in lector:
            str_a += col_a + ": " + col_b + "\n"
        print(str_a)
```

o usando al menos formateo de cadenas:

```
import csv

def listar_estados():
    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        str_a = ""
        for col_a, col_b in lector:
            str_a += f"{col_a}: {col_b}\n"
        print(str_a)
```

Si solo es para imprimir, entonces no uses una cadena intermedia:

```
import csv

def listar_estados():
    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        for col_a, col_b in lector:
            print(f"{col_a}: {col_b}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos paso por paso:

1. Cuando haces `lector = csv.reader(states)` lo que se guarda en `lector` es una lista con las filas del csv, es decir,

> En la posición `i` de la lista `lector` estará la fila i del csv

2. Lo que hace `join` es insertar después de cada posición de la lista "\n". Por lo tanto para cambiarlo por un for sería:

```
    def listarEstados():
        with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
            lector = csv.reader(states)
            strA = ""
            for row in lector:
                strA += row + "\n"
            strB = strA.replace(",",": ")
        print(strB)
```

3. Por último faltaría el `replace`. Como su nombre indica, lo que hace es cambiar la primera cadena por la segunda. Con un simple bucle y un if se podría hacer:

```
    def listarEstados():
        with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
            lector = csv.reader(states)

            #JOIN
            strA = ""
            for row in lector:
                strA += row + "\n"

            #REPLACE
            strB= ""
            for caracter in strA:
                if caracter == ",":
                    resultado += ": "
                else:
                    resultado += caracter

            print(strB)
```